# How do I deploy Microsoft Word add in, in the production?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ms-word, office-addins

I have created an add in using the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/yeoman-generator-overview)

Now in my local I am able to run in by doing `npm start` or `yarn start`.

But I want to deploy it on [AppSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/marketplace/submit-to-appsource-via-partner-center).

I have my company's account and everything there but I am finding it difficult how do I make it work? What are the steps to deploy it on AWS/EC2? I have deployed it on 3000 port on Windows EC2 instance but it's not working? I have been trying to find proper documentation or even a guide which shows how you can deploy it end to end?

What should I add in `manifest.xml` how do I deploy it on AWS and then later publish it to the AppSource?